# How to make comic panels in Blender?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

I am working on my personal project, trying to make comic from Blender.

The problem is: i don't know how to make Blender render 1 whole page for me without do it once for each panel separate and edit it later in other software.

[image]

For example: If i am working with this page in Unity

I will set up 1 "Main Camera", 5 "Panel Camera" and 5 Planes. 5 planes will be put at position fit with the paper, then they will collect data from 5 "Panel camera" and use them as texture. After that "Main camera" will render the whole things out as once. (Similar with how people making the minimap in games)

But i don't know how to do it in Blender (cycles). Is there any way for me to do it ?

Thank you in advantage.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to export the object with texture, or an image generated from camera view?

Comment: That's definitely a job for an image editing software like inkscape or gimp. Not saying it's impossible to do in Blender but it would be much more complicated to set up and you'd probably still need to render each panel separately anyway